# virtual memory and size of each item

Tags: linux, operating-system

I have this question with the answer, but still I don't understand some of them. Can you explain them?

Consider a system with 16-bit virtual addresses, wherein 12 bits are used for the page offset. For each question below, please answer the question and briefly justify your answer, or indicate “Unknown”, if the answer cannot be ascertained from the information provided.

(a) How large are the virtual pages?
2^12 bytes

(b) How large are the physical pages?
2^12 bytes

(c) How large is a single process’s virtual address space (in bytes)?
2^16 bytes

(d) How many physical pages exist? 
Unknown

(e) How many virtual pages exist, globally, across all processes running on the system? 
Unknown

Answer (score 0):

`a+b)` 12 bits used for offset. How many addresses can you address with 12 bits ?

The answer is: `2^12`. This is why page size is `2^12 = 4096 bytes = 4KB`

`c)` how many addresses can you address with 16 bits ? `2^16 B` this is the virtual address.

`d)`#frames = main-memory-size / page-size` which is unknown due to not knowing the physical memory size.

`e)` depends on number of processes in system.

Answer (score 0):

In virtual address,

The size of page offset account for the number of bytes inside one page since one offset points to one byte in physical memory. Here it is 12 bits so number bytes in one page is `2^12`. `(a)`

The size of page numbers account for total number of pages frames in virtual memory. Here page size is 4 bits long, 16-12, so total number of pages is `2^4`.

`(b)` since page size equals page frame size, it equals `2^12` bytes.

`(c)` virtual address space = total page numbers * page size = `2^4` * `2^12` = `2^16` (can be calculated directly from number of bits in virtual address).

`(d)` you can not tell number of frames from virtual address space. The point of having virtual address space is ability to allocate memory much larger than available physical size.

`(e)` every process can have up to `2^4` virtual pages. So total number of virtual pages depends on number of processes.